# Progress Bar in JSP

Tags: jsp, progress-bar

I am firing some kind of request to servlet which takes time to process that request. The request takes some time to complete. Because of this delay, I want to show the servlet progress in a JSP progress bar. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to load jsp and after that to get needed data via ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

**if you get the progress that is the percentage ,then you can show it in a jsp using**

1. Websocket connection
2. jquery
3. ajax

   The webSocket connection is a bi-directional connection.It is a simple class with @serverEndpoint.
   the listener within the servlet can pass the progress status(%) to the websocket and the serverendpoint passes value to jsp.The jsp shows the progress using jquery.thats it.
   The ajax call is used for post form submit.

If you dont want to use websockets then use plugins like uploadify etc..